# Pegar o histórico de revisão no Google Drive com Java pelo NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, google-drive-api

Preciso pegar o histórico de revisão do Google Drive. Visitei o site de developers do Drive e vi que tem como fazer isso com várias linguagens. Quero fazer com Java e uso NetBeans e o histórico que quero é o do Google Docs. O código já vem pronto para pegar o histórico mas precisa ter a biblioteca. Baixei a biblioteca [neste link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2).

E então adiciono no NetBeans (já adicionei a biblioteca e os `jar` files). Fiz como dizem pra fazer mas nada deu certo. Como fazer isso? O código que dá erro por não ter a biblioteca são essas 3 linhas:

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Revision;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.RevisionList;
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> package [name] doesnt exist

O que preciso fazer?

***obs: o resto da programação é a seguinte(retirada diretamente do site do google developers, no item revisão > list):***

```
    package javaapplication8;    

    import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
    import com.google.api.services.drive.model.Revision;
    import com.google.api.services.drive.model.RevisionList;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;



    public class MyClass {

      private static List<Revision> retrieveRevisions(Drive service,
      String fileId) {

          fileId = "1XpNdeTFBr2KygyfPtlowBvkpcaJJzjgLckrGjp5oOhg0";
      try {
        RevisionList revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId).execute();
        return revisions.getItems();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro(de compilação) ocorre porque nenhuma das bibliotecas que importaste do link enviado possui as classes que pretendes utilizar, do pacote:

`import com.google.api.services.drive`.

Por este facto tens o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixe [esta](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgoogleapiservicesdrivev2rev881142betajar.htm) versão, ela possui o que precisas. [Veja](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/overview-summary.html) a API.